# Working on an angular project for the first time, I want to know how can we extract an id from a url based on a click

Tags: angular, api

I am basically working with an api that accepts a request with an id. Now, based on a click on a card on one page, I want to open another page that contains the respective id sent in the request. I then want to extract the id and render the respective item with that id. It is hardcoded for now though. Below is the code..

```
    <div class="inside-items" (click)="showData()">
     <div class="product-img d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
     <a routerLink="/product-description"><img style="height: -webkit-fill-available;                              ;"  src="{{product.product_image}}"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="down-details">
     <a routerLink="/product-description"><h4>{{product.name}}</h4></a>
     <p>{{product.short_description}}</p>
     <label class="price">₹ {{product.max_quantity}}</label>
     <button class="btn gray-btn">ADD TO BAG</button>
   </div>
 </div>
```

This is the code for card, a click on any part should redirect this to product description page rendered with product of respective id.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!!

Comment: Read all of this: https://angular.io/guide/router

Answer (score 1):

Have this on the view of the component that navigates to the product description page:

```
<a routerLink="/product/{{product.id}}">{{product.name}}</a>
```

Have this on the product description component:

```
@Component({
  //...
})

export class ProductDescriptionComponent implements OnInit {
  id: string;
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  )
}

@ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.subscribe(
     params => {
       this.id = params['id'];
       //make your API call here with the ID
     }
  )
}
```

Make sure you have the product description page routing in your routing module like this:

```
const ProductRoutes: Routes = [
  //....
  {path: 'product/:id', component:  ProductDescriptionComponent}
]
```